# Can't get list to another else if block

Tags: c#

My goal is to get the list ,StudentFirstName working into the else if statement below. There is more code but I don't know if it is relevant for this, so just ask and I'll post the rest. I'm really unsure what to do next as there seems to be little info on the specifics of lists and their limits, just started btw so I'd appreciate the help.

```
            if (command == "Add" || command == "add")
            {

                List<string> StudentFirstName = new List<string>();
                List<string> StudentLastName = new List<string>();
                List<int> StudentID = new List<int>();
                string studentfirstname;
                string studentlastname;
                int studentid;

                Console.Write("Enter first name : ");
                studentfirstname = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter last name : ");
                studentlastname = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Enter student ID : ");
                studentid = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                StudentFirstName.Add(studentfirstname);
                StudentLastName.Add(studentlastname);
                StudentID.Add(studentid);
                Console.WriteLine("\nInfo has been saved!");
                mainMenu();
            }
            else if (command == "Remove" || command == "remove")
            {
                foreach (string student in StudentFirstName)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(student);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You declare `StudentFirstName` in the scope of the `if ` statement, therefore it is not accessible in the `else if` statement. You probably want to declare `StudentFirstName` as field or property of your class.

Comment: I assume this is running inside a loop? You will need to declare and instantiate `StudentFirstName` and `StudentLastName` outside/before entering the llop

Comment: A pair of `{` brackets `}` around a *block* of code determines a *scope* in C and C-derived languages (like C++, Java and C#).  Variable defined within a scope are known only within that scope (the variables are *scoped* to the *block*).  If you want to see them in another scope, you need to move their declaration to an *outer* scope that encompasses both scopes.  In your case, declare them before your `if` statement

Comment: Looking more carefully at your code, you need to move those initializations outside the scope of the `if` as well.  You instantiate (/construct) a new set of lists as soon as you get into the `if` block.  Then you add one thing.  When you get to the end of the block (at the closing `}`), those variables no longer exist.  The next time you enter the block, you get a new variable and a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever variables you want to access in the `else` need to be declared outside of the `if` block. Eg

```
List<string> StudentFirstName; // declare here
if (command.ToLower() == "add")
{
    StudentFirstName = new List<string>(); // accessible here
    ...
}
else if (command.ToUpper() == "REMOVE")
{
    foreach (string student in StudentFirstName) // and accessible here
    ...
}
```

(As an aside, you can simplify your `command` string test using `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` as shown.)